# C++11 std::compare_exchange_strong does not compile when comparing with null pointer

Tags: multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, atomic, compare-and-swap

I am working on a parallel avl tree and have ran into a problem. Here is the function that causes this problem:

```
template<typename T, int Threads>
bool PTreeSet<T, Threads>::tryInsert(Node* parent, Node* node) {
    if (parent->key > node->key) {
        return parent->left.compare_exchange_strong(nullptr, node); // <-- Error
    } else if (parent->key < node->key) {
        return parent->right.compare_exchange_strong(nullptr, node); // <-- Error
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`parent->left`has type `atomic<Node*>`and I want to set that pointer to `node` if the current value is null. The compiler complains with error

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'compare_exchange_strong'
        return parent->left.compare_exchange_strong(nullptr, node);
```

Why is this not valid code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of `atomic<T>::compare_exhange_strong` is a `T&`. It requires an lvalue. That's one half of the "exchange": the current value of the atomic is loaded into the object referred to by the first parameter.

You need something like this:

```
Node* tmp = nullptr;
parent->left.compare_exchange_strong(tmp, node);
```

As a side effect, if `parent->left` is not in fact `NULL`, you get its current value in tmp (which you can ignore if you don't need it, of course).