# Using compare_exchange_strong on atomic booleans (C++)

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

I'm new to concurrent programming and I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
private:
  std::atomic<bool> resizing_;

void Resize() { if (resizing_.compare_exchange_strong(false, true)... }
```

This throws `error: no matching member function for call to 'compare_exchange_strong'` and I'm not sure how I can fix this. I've tried using a `bool*` for the first argument but that didn't seem to help. I've tried to read the documentation on `atomic<>`s but it hasn't helped.

Any information on what I'm doing wrong would be really helpful!

Comment: The first argument to [`compare_exchange_strong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) need to be an [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) (e.g. the name of a variable), since it needs to bind to an l-value reference. `false` is a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), which cannot bind to an l-value reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 std::compare\_exchange\_strong does not compile when comparing with null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146682/c11-stdcompare-exchange-strong-does-not-compile-when-comparing-with-null-poi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of the `compare_exchange_strong` method is a reference to the type. This method *exchanges* two values, but only if the *comparison* of the `contained` value and the `expected` value is true. Otherwise it replaces the expected with the contained value.

The idiom is like this:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> value;

int expected = value;
do {
    int new_value = get_updated_value(expected);
} while(!value.compare_exchange_strong(expected, new_value));
```

Note that the `expected` is automatically updated whenever the comparison is false, and another `new_value` is evaluated each iteration.